# Give wood script

Tags: lua, roblox

This script is supposed to give people 10 wood when clicking on the tree. But it's not working and there is no error. I think the line `local wood = player:WaitForChild("leaderstats"):WaitForChild("Wood")` is the problem

```
local clickDetector = workspace.Tree.ClickDetector
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local wood = player:WaitForChild("leaderstats"):WaitForChild("Wood")

function onMouseClick()
    wood.Value += 10
end

clickDetector.MouseClick:connect(onMouseClick)
```

This script is working fine:

```
local clickDetector = workspace.Tree.ClickDetector
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local wood = player:WaitForChild("leaderstats"):WaitForChild("Wood")
    
function onMouseClick()
    print("Working")
end    

clickDetector.MouseClick:connect(onMouseClick)
```

This my leaderboard

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

local function leaderboardSetup(player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")

    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = player
    
    local coins = Instance.new("IntValue")
    coins.Name = "Coins"
    coins.Value = 0
    coins.Parent = leaderstats
    
    local points = Instance.new("IntValue")
    points.Name = "Wood"
    points.Value = 0
    points.Parent = leaderstats
end

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(leaderboardSetup)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is your question? (And what is _the problem_ you mentioned?) Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
local clickDetector = workspace.Tree.ClickDetector
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local wood = player:WaitForChild("leaderstats"):WaitForChild("Wood")

function onMouseClick(plr)
    plr.leaderstats.Wood.Value += 10
end

clickDetector.MouseClick:connect(onMouseClick)
```

> This code works but if your item is respawnable it will break